# Does MPI use TCP (or TCP like) packets delivery or can lose packages on MPI_Send?

Tags: tcp, mpi, packet, loss

Does MPI use TCP (or TCP like guaranteed) packets delivery or can lose packages on MPI_Send?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation detail does not matter.

The MPI standards mandates message are delivered (and in the right order) so no "packet" is ever lost.